# I can't figure out how to count an alias [mysql]

Tags: mysql, count, alias, datediff

I have to find the difference between two(2) dates and count how many time the results duplicate

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(name.shipped, name.order) AS 'days', COUNT(*)
FROM name
Group by 'days'
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

however; instead of having multiple rows, I only get one(1) row with the count of the other rows.

```
days | count(*)
  4     16
```

---

Comment: You probably want `GROUP BY days`, not `GROUP BY 'days'`.

Comment: Why not `SELECT DATEDIFF(name.shipped, name.order) AS 'days', COUNT(*)
FROM name
Group by name.shipped, name.order`

Comment: WOW I just tried @ceejayoz and it worked -.- thanks guys!

Comment: in my sql single quote `'` stand for strings, you use back ticks ```' ` ' ``` to indicate alias or fieldnames.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're wanting to group by the static string `'days'` (you don't!), you want `GROUP BY days`, not `GROUP BY 'days'`.

Comment: would help also name your alias ```' `days` '```